# How to create a foreign key in MongoDB with Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, foreign-keys

I've a simple "table" user, where each user has a `username`, an `email` and a `password`. Into `users.js`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        email:    { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        password: { type: String, required: true }
    },
    { collection: 'users' }
)

const model = mongoose.model('UserSchema', UserSchema)

module.exports = model
```

Now, I want to define an `account`. One user can have one or more bank account. For example, I can have `account_1` with a balance of `100$`, `account_2` with a balance of `200$` and so on. The problem is that the collection `accounts`, has two parameters: one is the `user` (and this is a foreign key, because it's the user nickname in the collection `users`), and the other one is the `balance` (a simple number). Into `accounts.js`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        balance:  { type: Number, required: true},
    },
    { collection: 'accounts' }
    
)

const model = mongoose.model('AccountSchema', AccountSchema)

module.exports = model
```

How can I say that the username into `AccountSchema` is the field of `UserSchema`?

Answer (score 0):

You use refs in mongoose.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "user },
        balance:  { type: Number, required: true},
    },
    { collection: 'accounts' }
    
)

const model = mongoose.model('AccountSchema', AccountSchema)
```

> Note: The ref should be the name you passed as the first parameter to the `mongoose.model` function in your `users` model.